# dropdownlist in gridview header template column not firiring the OnSelectedIndexChanged event

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have the below definition of a an Asp.net Gridview in a asp.net userControl.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdTabularView" CssClass="standard HeadCenter rowborder cellborder" Width="100%"
            runat="server" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="even" 
             HeaderStyle-CssClass="HeaderFreez"  
             AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableModelValidation="True" Height="80px" onpageindexchanging="OnPaging">                            
            <EmptyDataRowStyle/>
            <Columns>
<%--         year
--%>    <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate>
            Year:
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlYear" runat="server"
             OnSelectedIndexChanged = "YearChanged" AutoPostBack = "true"
            AppendDataBoundItems = "true" >
            <asp:ListItem Text = "ALL" Value = "ALL"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("Year")%>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>                    
                <center class="bold">
                No data available.
                </center>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderFreez" HorizontalAlign = "Center"></HeaderStyle>                                        
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="even RowStyle"></AlternatingRowStyle>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Below is how i populated the DropDownList with a list of years to filter the grid data by.

```
private void BindYearList(DropDownList ddlYear)
    {
        ddlYear.DataSource = objDataTable.DefaultView;
        ddlYear.DataTextField = "Year";
        ddlYear.DataValueField = "Year";
        ddlYear.DataBind();
        ddlYear.Items.FindByValue(ViewState["YearFilter"].ToString()).Selected = true;
    }
```

I want the function below to executed on the OnSelectedIndexChanged event  of the DropDownList but it isn't firing.

```
 protected void YearChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddlYear = (DropDownList)sender;
        ViewState["YearFilter"] = ddlYear.SelectedValue;
        objDataTable = drawChartGridOnly(htParameters, out dt, "");
        myDataGrid.DataSource = objDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Field = '{0}'", ViewState["Filter"].ToString());
        myDataGrid.DataBind();
    }
```

I already have this `OnSelectedIndexChanged = "YearChanged" AutoPostBack = "true"` in the DropDownList's markup but is isn't making any diffference.

Does any one know what i could be doing wrong in the GridViews source above? The grid is in a .ascx user control.

**Below is how i call BindYearList**

```
DropDownList ddlYear = (DropDownList)grdTabularView.HeaderRow.FindControl("ddlYear");
this.BindYearList(ddlYear);
ddlYear.DataBind();
```

**And below is how a bind the Grid**

```
  grdTabularView.DataSource = objDataTable.DefaultView ;
  grdTabularView.DataBind();
  grdTabularView.HeaderRow.Visible = true;
  grdTabularView.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you use to bind the grid view, it might be related to the problem? Also how are you calling BindYearList?

Comment: The Most common cause of such kind of issues is that the Original Event (OnSelectedIndexChanged) is lost due to a new set of  Events being raised on account of incorrect databindings. Wherever you do Databinding , Check if  it is  inside an " if ( ! IsPostBack ) " . Else show your Page_Load Code